# It is possible to mock custom attributes c#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

It is possible to mock custom attributes c#?

For example:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)] 
public class YourAttribute : Attribute
{
}

[Your]
public void MyMethod()
{
   //something
}
```

I want to test the MyMethod, but I need to simulate the attribute Your.

Comment: The short answer is no, but what does the attribute do?

Comment: But how can I test this method?

Comment: Generally speaking you should test the attribute in isolation. In other words, it should execute shared code that can then be tested as a unit.

Comment: The problem is that this attribute prevents me from testing the method. So I want to mock it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add an attribute to an instance or to a type via TypeDescriptor; following example uses Moq, but it can be applied elsewhere.

```
var mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();

var attribute = new YourAttribute();

TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(mock.Object, attribute);
```